# How to implement the animation associated to the pinch gesture in "Photos"?

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there a pre-built animation in iOS APIs for the effect you have in "Photos" app on ipad ?

I'm referring to the animation associated to the pinch gesture over pictures albums: [image]

I need to implement a similar effect in my app, to display a group of pictures.

thanks

Comment: anyone can provide some help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no built in animation for that. You have to implement it yourself unfortunately.